# How cant I get ng-model value and label value into one object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get such array from input form:

```
"data":[
    {"name": "Name", "values": ["Jack"]},
    {"name": "Age",  "values": ["67"]},
    {"name": "Hobby","values": ["swimming"]}
]
```

I'm trying this:
This is my Form with label and input, I need them both to put in one object, but can't understand how to do this

```
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.name">
         </div>
         <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.name)">
         </div>
    </div>
```

This is my controller, I put the data to the LocalStorage:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    $scope.data = $scope.data ? JSON.parse($scope.data) : {};
    $scope.$watchCollection('data', function(newVal, oldVal){
       localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify($scope.formData));
    });
}
```

Comment: Data is an array.  There is no property called `.name`.  Perhaps you need to pull a specific element from the array.  Did you mean to use `ng-repeat` to traverse the entire array?  Or just pull a specific element like `data[0].name`?

Comment: @ryanyuyu  mmm, yes, something like this, but instead of [0] I want label text. for example <label>Company</label><input type="text" ng-model="data['Company'].name">  Would be this correct? Or is there another solution?

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to bind to.  Some property that applies to all the data?  A property of a specific element within the array?

Comment: @ryanyuyu     I'm trying to get such array as at the beginning of my post. Look at it, it has the same values "name" and "value" . For example here http://jsfiddle.net/rabidGadfly/CUzbs/   it gives me this object:  {"firstName":"Mick","lastName":"Tomson"}  But I want this:  [{name: "firstName", value: "Mick"}, {name:"lastName", value:"Tomson"},.. ] and so on. It's more clear? Sorry for my explanation

Comment: Ok I see.  Your data object is pretty messed up.  If I understand this correctly, your data is an array of key-value pairs where the key is the name of the property and the value is the actual data?  That's a pretty convoluted way to do things if you don't intend on using all the data in an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes! Actualy I'm not going to use ng-repeat because there is not always input field but also could be select tag or something else

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but in your code you want to set the ng-model attribute to be the actual value that is being changed:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data[0].values[0]">
     </div>
</div>
```

Though I would recommend you change your model to look like this instead:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": "67",
    "hobby": "swimming"
  }
}
```

Then the code you posted in the OP would work.

Comment: Would it correct if I do like this: ng-model="data['Name' (this is the label text here instead of zero)].values  ? Or is there another solution?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how objects and arrays work in javascript.

data['name'] is the same as data.name.

Comment: no, I understand, I guess my problem is that I'm making an empty object at the beginning while verifying if the LocalStorage is empty. Thanks! I think I've understood

Comment: Sorry for my explanation I'll try again:
I receive this object:
{"firstName":"Mick","lastName":"Tomson"}, because first input has ng-model="data.firstName" and second "data.LastName" .
But I want to be like this:
 [{name: "firstName", value: "Mick"}, {name:"lastName", value:"Tomson"},.. ]   and so on. firstName is a label text, value is the input value and this is one object and so on

Comment: You would have to manually assign those values to your object in either the controller or service layer.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use a regular object model, and then later convert to your array format.

Comment: @Daniel Cottone  sure, I did answer above of the topic right now, but it still doesn't work correctly, because now LocalStorage doesn't work

Comment: Don't put it in localStorage, just put it in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `ng-repeat` to do this.

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wESQQCmhoW9qSxNZBDcU?p=preview)

Comment: no no, I want from input to get such object: [{name: "Input name Name", value: "Mick"}, {name: "Input name Age", value: 11}...]  and so on

Comment: I don't understand. Label in the form are static data or pulled from the controller?  Can you create an example and be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:
Instead of empty object {} I set var list

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    var list = [
                 {name: "Name", value: ""},
                 {name: "Last Name", value: ""}
                   /* and so on... */]
    $scope.data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    $scope.data = $scope.data ? JSON.parse($scope.data) : list;
    $scope.$watchCollection('data', function(newVal, oldVal){
       localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify($scope.formData));
    });
}
```

But now it doen't work with LocalStorage, I guess something wrong with $watch.

I did edit, instead of $watchCollection I use

```
$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal), localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify($scope.formData) )} ,true);
```

True allows to dig deeper.

Now everything is good, the lesson is over, Thanks to all you guys!